# Docker Image works with docker-compose up but not on Amazon ECS or Heroku

Tags: django, postgresql, docker, heroku, amazon-ecs

I am trying to host a Django project with a Postgres database in a Docker container. The project is a practice e-commerce site with a database for product info. I was able to get it working with docker-compose up and accessed the site running in the container at localhost:8000 but when I tried hosting it on AWS it didn't work. I uploaded the image to ECR and started a cluster. When I tried running a task with the image, it showed PENDING but as soon as I tried to refresh, the task was gone. I tried setting up cloudwatch logs but they were empty since the task was stopping immediately after starting. After that I tried hosting on Heroku. I was able to deploy the image but when I tried to open the app it showed an error (shown below).

It feels like the image is just failing immediately whenever I try hosting it anywhere, but it works fine when I use docker-compose up. I think I'm making a very basic mistake (I'm a total beginner at all this) but not sure what it is. Thanks for taking the time to help.

I'll also add my Dockerfile and docker-compose.yml

Error Message from Heroku

```
2022-11-25T05:13:31.719689+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H14 desc="No web processes running" method=GET path="/" host=hk-comic-app.herokuapp.com request_id=ea683b1d-e869-4ea9-98aa-2b9ed08f7219 fwd="98.116.68.242" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2022-11-25T05:22:36.083750+00:00 app[api]: Scaled to app@1:Free by user 
2022-11-25T05:22:39.300239+00:00 heroku[app.1]: Starting process with command `python3`
2022-11-25T05:22:39.895200+00:00 heroku[app.1]: State changed from starting to up
2022-11-25T05:22:40.178736+00:00 heroku[app.1]: Process exited with status 0
2022-11-25T05:22:40.228638+00:00 heroku[app.1]: State changed from up to crashed
2022-11-25T05:22:40.232742+00:00 heroku[app.1]: State changed from crashed to starting
2022-11-25T05:22:43.937389+00:00 heroku[app.1]: Starting process with command `python3`
2022-11-25T05:22:44.610097+00:00 heroku[app.1]: State changed from starting to up
2022-11-25T05:22:45.130636+00:00 heroku[app.1]: Process exited with status 0
2022-11-25T05:22:45.180808+00:00 heroku[app.1]: State changed from up to crashed
2022-11-25T05:23:09.462805+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H14 desc="No web processes running" method=GET path="/" host=hk-comic-app.herokuapp.com request_id=f4cc3e04-0257-4336-94b3-7e48094cabd4 fwd="98.116.68.242" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
```

Dockerfile

```
FROM python:3.9-slim-buster
ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED=1
WORKDIR /django
COPY requirements.txt requirements.txt
RUN pip3 install -r requirements.txt
```

docker-compose.yml

```
version: "3"
services:
  app:
    build: .
    volumes:
      - .:/django
      - ./wait-for-it.sh:/wait-for-it.sh
    ports:
      - 8000:8000
    image: app:django
    container_name: django_container
    command: /wait-for-it.sh db:5432 -- python3 manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000
    depends_on:
      - db
  db:
    image: postgres
    volumes:
      - ./data/db:/var/lib/postgresql/data
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_DB=comic_db
      - POSTGRES_USER=comic_user
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=password
    container_name: postgres_db
```

Comment: You don't need to use command in docker-compose file while in production

Comment: This isn't a problem with the container, but rather with how you're trying to run it. Are you deploying via the container registry (with `heroku container:push`) or the container stack (with a `heroku.yml` file)?

Comment: I tried heroku container:push only. Is this ignoring the docker-compose.yml file?

Answer (score 0):

Heroku doesn't use `docker-compose.yml`. You'll need to make a few changes:

1. Update your `Dockerfile` to include a [command](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#cmd) that should be used to run your application, e.g.

   ```
   CMD gunicorn project_name.wsgi
   ```

   This shouldn't impact your development environment since your `docker-compose.yml` overrides the command. You'll need to make sure Gunicorn (or whatever WSGI server you choose to use) is declared as a dependency.
2. Update your Django application to get its PostgreSQL connection string from the `DATABASE_URL` environment variable that Heroku provides. A common way to do that is by adding a dependency on [`dj-database-url`](https://pypi.org/project/dj-database-url/) and then changing your `DATABASES` setting accordingly:

   ```py
   DATABASES["default"] = dj_database_url.config()
   ```

   I suggest you read the documentation for that library as there's more than one way to use it.

   For example, you can optionally set a default connection for development via a `default` argument here. Or, if you prefer, you could set your own `DATABASE_URL` environment variable in your `docker-compose.yml`.
3. [Provision a PostgreSQL database](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-postgresql#provisioning-heroku-postgres) for your application. Make sure to do the first step to check whether you already have a database.

Then redeploy.